# Marmelade or Jam?

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, single-word-request

I am in high school learning German and one of the online tools we use taught us that jam was the same in German (Jam). However, our teacher told us that it was wrong and that we should use `Marmelade` instead.

What's the correct term for jam then? Is the site wrong or is our teacher wrong?

Comment: I never found *Jam*  claiming to be a German word, and it is quite exotic without a following *session*.

Comment: Closely related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3003/what-are-marmelade-konfit%c3%bcre-or-fruchtaufstrich

Comment: As you might expect, that site is very wrong and your teacher is absolutely correct.

Comment: Which of the very many meanings of English 'jam' do you want to translate? In German, both 'Jam' and 'Marmelade' can be correct translations depending on what you are really trying to translate. Other possible translations are Stau, Gedränge, Gewühl, Engpass or Ladehemmung just to mention a few.

Comment: If you use the word Jam in German, it would probably be often associated [with music](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jam-Session).

Comment: There actually *is* a German word "Jam" for (especially British) Marmelade and Duden knows about it - But hardly anyone else.

Answer (score 9):

Most common are

> Marmelade
>
> Konfitüre

These are more or less synonymous and mean a fruity jam with pieces of fruit in it. Swiss German speakers use *Konfitüre* more, Germans and Austrians *Marmelade*. Both are used both for English "marmalade" and English "jam".

Another word is

> Mus

This is for jams with no recognizeable pieces of fruit (though pips may still be in there). Most common is *Apfelmus* (applesauce), *Birnenmus*, and *Pflaumenmus*.

Comment: There is also *Gelée* which is a product made of fruit juice (not fruits). Also the EU ruled that "Marmelade" is to be used for products made of oitrus fruits only, but nobody really cares/knows about it and uses it for any kind of jam/marmelade.

Comment: @user1583209 Agreed, but the French spelling "Gelée" is rather rare in German. Usually, the word is written without the accent.

Comment: The bureaucratic correct term since the EU's decision mentioned by @user1583209 is *Fruchtaufstrich*, even if nobody uses it.

Comment: I feel urged to comment here that *Mus* is something completely different from *Marmelade*. *Marmelade* is, basically cooked fruit with added sugar and usually some other stuff for gelling (if the fruit itself does not have enough of that stuff), then put in jars to be durable. Whereas *Mus* is just the fruit without added sugar or gelling stuff, and usually eaten right away, so not with the idea of being durable. (Well, there  are jars of *Apfelmus* in the super markets... don't know how they make them durable. Probably by adding chemicals.)

Comment: Mus is filled into the packages hot, then sealed. Most times without any further preservatives. https://www.google.de/search?q=pflaumenmus&tbm=shop

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann That's true for "Apfelmus"; "[Pflaumenmus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pflaumenmus)", however, is very similar to jam. The main differences are the long cooking time and the reduced amount of added sugar.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that if I am stuck in a jam on my way home from work, I have to look out on the street for whole pieces of fruit to decide if I can say "Ich stecke in der Marmelade fest." or "Ich stecke in dem Muß fest." in German?

Comment: This is called *Stau* in German. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaHuPUiYVbI

Comment: @Janka I know that what I am talking about is called "Stau" in German. That's why I am wondering why you suggest to translate "jam" with "Marmelade" or "Konfitüre" without knowing if that is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: The OP's teacher suggested *Marmelade*. So *Stau* cannot be meant.